# Function to convert date to string for national holidays in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using google sheets and want to know if there is a formula that will check a date for a national holiday in the google system and then return the string associated with that date/holiday?

**For Example**

```
    ColA         ColB
   1-1-2018     New Years Day
```

What formula would I need to put in `b1` that would return **New Years Day** if `1-1-2018` was in `A1`?

Comment: Excel does not support that. You need to have a list with all your holidays that you want to work with and do a lookup in that list.

Comment: "I'm using google sheets" - so please don't use the Excel tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `importhtml` function to grab a reference table and then `query` that table to match the date in the adjacent cell. Here is an example of a formula you could use to reference a date in cell A1:

`=IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/","table",1),"select Col3 where Col4 = 'Federal Holiday' and Col1 = date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(A1),"2018-mm-dd")&"'", 0),"No Holiday Found")`